# Bluetooth Pairing at runtime on android marshmallow

Tags: android, bluetooth

```
private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exception: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}
```

I used the above code to pairing a available bluetooth device but in api level 23 it is not working.

I define the respective permission on the manifest file as well as I asked the permission at the at time, the other bluetooth operations worked fine but pairing is not happening.

Is there any other option available?